# Mod_security error on wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am getting this error in while clicking some submit in all the pages in my wordpress site

> Not Acceptable! 
>   An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security

I have tried this solution in my `htaccess` file but same error shows no changes occur please tell me to solve this issue it will be very helpful to me.

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If your host knows what they are doing they aren't going to let you turn off mod_security. Contact them for help determining what rule is being tripped and how to fix it.